# Get current user in ApplicationRecord Model and perform a query in has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a model Post with lot of relationships, the one I want to focus on is

```
has_many :grid_notifications, :dependent=>:destroy
```

I'm using jbuilder to return data to Backbone.js layer, so when I fetch posts **as_json** method is called

```
  def as_json(opts=nil)
  out={
    ...
    notifications: self.grid_notifications,
    ...
  }
  end
```

I defined views following jBuilder docs

**views/posts/index.json.jbuilder**

```
json.array! @posts, partial: 'posts/post', as: :post
```

and related partial  **views/posts/_post.json.jbuilder**

```
json.extract! post, ...other values... , :grid_notifications
```

In this way, foreach Post it returns all the GridNotifications, no matter which is the current user.
So, I'd like to perform query related to Post model to return GridNotifications of current user and not of all users, so **has_many** statement become

```
has_many :grid_notifications, -> { where user_id: user.id }, :dependent=>:destroy
```

But in this way I get the following error:

Showing .../app/views/posts/index.json.jbuilder where line #1 raised:
undefined local variable or method `user' for #

So, how I've to define **_post.json.jbuilder** or ?

Answer (score 0):

Use scope in model Post

```
scope :user_grid_notifications, -> (user) { includes(:grid_notifications).where(grid_notifications: {user_id: user.id}) }
```

and then

```
notifications: self.user_grid_notifications(current_user)
```

Comment: Tried this, but actually not works. I'm delving into it. Thanks for your reply Salil